# Transition effects in single video in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, avassetwriter, avvideocomposition

I want to add fade in/out, flip and page curl transition effects into a video created from array of images using `AVAssetWriter` and `AVAssetComposition`.

I saw ["Working with Media in AV Foundation"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/) talk about this starting at around 18:00, but it shows the fade effect between two videos. I want fade effects between every images in a single video. And also want flip and curl effects.

Comment: What'd you end up doing? Looking for something similar.

Comment: hi @JesseHead I dint find any solution for that till now (:

Comment: Same problem we also facing , How pass transition effect image array to AVAssetWriter , Can any one know about this